# Append dataframe in specific row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in the following format

```
a   b   label
1   5   A
2   6   A
3   7   A
4   8   B
1   5   B
2   6   B
5   6   C
3   2   C
```

I want append with new dataframe

```
a   b   label
3   4   A
```

The result become this

```
a   b   label
1   5   A
2   6   A
3   7   A
4   8   B
1   5   B
2   6   B
5   6   C
3   2   C
3   4   A <-- New Data
```

My question is how order new data become this every append new data

```
a   b   label
1   5   A
2   6   A
3   7   A
3   4   A <-- New Data
4   8   B
1   5   B
2   6   B
5   6   C
3   2   C
```

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,5,3], 
                         "b":[5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6,6,2],
                         "label":['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C']}) 

new_data = pd.DataFrame({"a":[3],
                         "b":[4],
                         "label":['A']})

df1 = df1.append(new_data,ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply sort it on the `label` column after the data frame append

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,5,3], 
                         "b":[5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6,6,2],
                         "label":['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C']}) 

new_data = pd.DataFrame({"a":[3],
                         "b":[4],
                         "label":['A']})

df1 = df1.append(new_data,ignore_index = True).sort_values(by='label')
```

Result :

```
a  b   label
1  5     A
2  6     A
3  7     A
3  4     A  <-- new data here
4  8     B
1  5     B
2  6     B
5  6     C
3  2     C
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution